# getting state from connect(mapStateToProps) > UNDEFINED

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am kind of struggling to get the state of book, when I log the props I get book: undefined.

Any tips?

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import BookForm from './BookForm';

const EditBook = (props) => {
 console.log(props)
  return (
    <div>
      hello
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    book: state.books.find((book) => book.id === props.match.params.id)
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EditBook);
```

Rest of the project is on my Github: https://github.com/bananafreak/bookshelf

Comment: Do some logging inside the mapStateToProps function. Log out the results of your find before you return it

Comment: Yeah when i do console.log(state) inside the mapStateToProps function, it returns the state correctly but once I want to access it in the component EditBook, then I get undefined

Comment: that's probably because none of your `books`  satisfies this test : `book.id === props.match.params.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the `Link` in the `BookListItem`. You don't need the **:** before `${id}`. The **:** is causing the problem.

```
<Link to={`/edit/${id}`}><h2>{title}</h2></Link>
```

In the `EditBook` component return the following

```
<BookForm {...props}></BookForm>
```

In the `BookForm` `constructor` set the state from `props.book`

```
this.state = { ...props.book }
```

Comment: yes, I managed to found it few minutes before you, many thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into issues with this before where `===` will fail because the types of `book.id` and `props.match.params.id` are different.  The `params` values are always strings - maybe try `parseInt(props.match.params.id)` or `==` comparison (with type coercion).

Comment: I checked `typeof` of both `book.id` and `props.match.params.id` | they are both strings

Answer (score 0):

I managed to found where was my mistake.

In the component BookListItem:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const BookListItem = ({ author, title, genre, text, id, pages }) => (
  <div>
    <Link to={`/edit/${id}`}><h2>{title}</h2></Link>
    <h3>by: {author}</h3>
    <p>{genre}</p>
    {pages > 0 && <p>{pages} pages</p>}
    <p>{text}</p>
    <p>-------------------------------</p>
  </div>
);

export default BookListItem;
```

Before the ${id} I had unfortunately colon {`/edit/:${id}`} so then book.id and props.match.params.id could not match